# How do I raise my luck by 2 during the zeta scan?

Tags: fallout-2

In fallout 2, the zeta scan you can do in NCR I have been told increases your luck by 2, however every time I do the scan it decreases it by 1! Is there a variable that changes this? Or is there a specific dialogue tree that you have to follow? My luck is 6 if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The Zeta Scan is totally random. All you can do is reload your game and try, till you get +2 luck.

Various sources back up my claim:

[Fallout 2 Guide](http://user.tninet.se/~jyg699a/fallout2.html)

[No Mutants Allowed forum](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=985&sid=108d80b6360e16b95587962388dbff2f)

[Gamefaqs Forum thread 1](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/63576-fallout-2/41366822)

[Gamefaqs Forum thread 2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/63576-fallout-2/48332150)